# Which software to quickly format and edit a price list

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation, page-layout, print-production, typesetting

I've been trying to design a price list using Photoshop, and it just feels like there should be a more efficient way to do it than writing and aligning boxes of text. I am trying to design something along the line of the picture below, and I feel like there should be a way of automatizing the process. Is there some other pieces of software or add-ons I can use?
[image: http://safiathebeautyparlour.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/5/4/12541687/9191631_orig.jpg]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InDesign is much, MUCH better at working with repeated styles. You align one "box", or paragraph as they call it, then apply the style and everything else gets aligned automatically. You edit the style, everything updates automatically.

You can import your background image and other pictures/logos as separate files.

It also handles fonts better because you don't need the fonts installed in your computer, just drop them in a "Document fonts" folder next to the source file. This is good if you are working with different clients as you don't need all their fonts permanently installed, which can slow down your operating system (as fonts can accumulate).

InDesign can also import data from Microsoft Excel XLS files so, with the proper skills you can edit this price list in XLS and update a ready-made design with just a few clicks.

Comment: That sounds excellent. Could you point me towards a tutorial that will help me design something like the price list above?

Comment: Youtube "indesign menu" and there will be many, ie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTtGu8X5UhE

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to, try using Indesign as first choice, and Illustrator as 2nd choice for making text documents like menus. Then you can use Photoshop to create the backgrounds or images which you can place into Indesign or Illustrator.

Comment: Absolutely.  And when the user zooms, they will look good instead of turning pixely.  And the resulting PDFs will be smaller too, and search engines will pick up their contents because they are internally stored as text rather than pixels.